# matplotlib format_coord with TeX markup

Tags: matplotlib

I am using the format_coord callback to pretty up a contour plot, ie :

```
    ax = subplot(111)
    ax.contourf(xx, yy, zz, cmap='jet')
    ...
    z = interp2d(xx, yy, zz)
    def format_coord(x,y):
        return r'$f_x(%1.4f, %1.4f) = %1.4f$' % (x,y, z(x,y))
    ax.format_coord = format_coord
```

It all works except the text is not rendered to TeX markup, just the raw string with the $ signs appears ... is there a way to force this through the matplotlib TeX rendering markup

Also I noticed the same issue in Figure(num=...) (though this is the system window I think and I don't really expect it to work), eg:

```
 Figure(num=r'$f_x$')
```

renders just $f_x$ for the figure name

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the same as with figure numbers, tex rendering only works in the plot itself (the thing you get upon calling `savefig()`.

Comment: I figured this might be the case, but I was hoping I might be able to manually force it through some render function, but I guess the destination (ie the OS figure title or the toolbar) would have to support displaying this, which I assume it does not ?

Comment: I guess you can embed the figure in a GUI, include some suitable widget , capture mouse events, render the tex (matplotlib must have a function for this somewhere?) and update the widget.